# Can I search flights by price and not by destination?

Tags: air-travel, money

I might be taking part in a challenge where you have to get as far away from the starting location as you can in 36 hours. The challenge is that you have to raise all the money on the day.

This has given rise to an interesting question - is there a way I can search for all the flights out from a given airport, and sort them by price.

I can easily see all the departures from an airport using a site like [Flight Radar 24](https://www.flightradar24.com/airport/ema/arrivals), but I can't see the prices of these flights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly but can search to *Everywhere* on Skyscanner or *Anywhere* on Adioso. On Skyscanner the results will be sorted by price. So if you just ignore anything after your intended price,  this will be the list of most flights below the price.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I was after - now I need to have a think as to how I can raise £30!

Comment: @Tim look in the couch cushions and under the car seat! :)

Answer (score 0):

Skyscanner is a very good web/app, that allows you to search with

1) your origin >> gives all cheapest destinations sorted by lowest price with different time ranges

2) your origin and time >> gives all cheapest destinations sorted by lowest price